# Why won't the background color apply?

Tags: css

I know the solution has to be trivial, but I am just not able to figure out why the background color from my class ('highlight') is not applying to the links marked 'sniff it here'. Sometimes it seems to apply for a moment, and then disappears. See the page here:

http://www.foodsniffr.com/blog/pumpkin-cranberry-oatmeal-cookies-vegan-vegetarian-gluten-free-healthy/

Comment: highlight where? to wich item in your page?

Comment: sorry, link marked 'sniff it here'

Comment: look at the console you're getting an error for the css load

Comment: What color do you want it to highlight?

Comment: I'm getting a 404 for the style.css

Comment: no worries, the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats weird. The included `light.css` *(which has the* `.highlight` *style)* gets rewritten to `I.light.css.pagespeed.cf.kioUqT0sFU.css` *(which lacks that style)*, while the `style.css` isn't rewritten and throws a 404. I am assuming it's a caching problem of Wordpress, and not related to CSS.

Comment: Take a look at what styles are missing in the rewritten css page. If you made a typo (missing } or ; for example), it might not recognize any styles coming after that.

Comment: thanks, you gave me a clue that the problem lay with caching. It appears we had enabled pagespped on the server end, in addition to WP cache. Pagespeed was causing these issues.